# Can't login graphically on ubuntu 20.04.1 commands too slow

Tags: 20.04, login, lts

My ubuntu desktop never finishes login in graphical mode after an update, I try to login with ctr + alt + f3 but every executed command is terribly slow (even `ls`). I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and edited /etc/gdm3/custom.conf without luck. Don't know what else to do. Please help

`grep "install" /var/log/dpkg.log` shows

[dpkg.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0JJ4.jpg)

`df -x squashfs -h --total` shows

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu3U3.jpg)

`lscpu` shows

[lscpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NUKq.jpg)

`smartctl -t short /dev/sda6` is stuck in (90% remaining)

Comment: I would cleanly shutdown (SysRq keys direct to kernel if necessary) then explore your system from *live* media. Is there disk space, is there issues with drive (SMART health), I'd likely look at clues in `dmesg` or `journalctl` before the reboot, but you've provided few specifics as to your hardware so I'd alter according to that. You're also mentioning packages (`lightdm`) which don't exist on a clean install, so I'd explore what changes were made & look for them creating issues (you gave no specifics on recent changes...)

Comment: I have added information

Comment: @daaan Here are some things you can try.
[1] You say that it has started to do this since an update? On the boot menu, you should see an "advanced options" entry after the main ones. If you choose this, you can boot with your old kernel and see if it makes any difference.
[2] See if the behaviour still occurs if you boot from a Live USB medium.
[3] I also recommend trying to use a DOS bootable USB key to update your firmware. This often helps, in my experience.